# Reload jsTree data return in an Ajax Request

Tags: jstree

My jsTree contains html data that is set when the tree loads (see javascript below).  This works correctly.  However, I want to be able to reload the entire tree in an Ajax request based on certain user actions.  I basically need to reload all the tree data returned from the Ajax request.  Is this possible?

My current code is below:

```
function setJoinType(node, joinType) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "qbwizard.aspx/SetJoinType",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'alias': '" + node[0].id + "', 'joinType': '" + joinType + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: RedrawJoinSummary,
        error: AjaxFailed
    });
    return true;
}
function RedrawJoinSummary(data) {
    //$("#tvJoinSummary").jstree('destroy'); 
    $("#tvJoinSummary").jstree("html", data.d);
    $("#tvJoinSummary").jstree("refresh", -1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Radek.

I actually got this to work by putting the jstree intialization code into a function (tvJoinWorkspaceTreeviewScriptInit) and then calling that function after resetting the html. The probably is that the nodes all lose their state (opened / closed). I decided to use Ajax callbacks and javascript to build the tree again because it ended up being much easier to do.

```
$("div#tvJoinWorkspace").html(data);
$("#tvJoinWorkspace").jstree("destroy");
tvJoinWorkspaceTreeviewScriptInit(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one? If you define your tree by

`$("#jstree").jstree({` and you html is

```
<div id="tree">
  <div id="jstree">
  </div>
</div>
```

then you can

replace the `<div id="jstree"></div>` with something like `<div id="jstree_ajax"></div>`